# Question, should we eliminate or change the reason to close regarding company specific policies?

Tags: discussion

Here is the reason in question:

•"Questions seeking advice on company-specific regulations, agreements, or policies should be directed to your manager or HR department. Questions that address only a specific company or position are of limited use to future visitors. Questions seeking legal advice should be directed to legal professionals. For more information, click here."

I think this reason is the most abused reason to close on this site.  It is also a bit murky in it's wording as it really contains **TWO** reasons.  1)Company specific policies are off topic 2)Legal advice is off topic.

I think the first should be replaced with something like "Too narrow" (we do have too broad as a reason).  The second could stand alone as "Legal advice is off topic" and then the instruction to seek legal counsel.

Agree/disagree?

Comment: Related: http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/4004/can-we-remove-the-legal-advice-from-the-off-topic-close-reason  IMO that's the better suggestion for this close reason.

Comment: The problem is "Legal Advice is off topic"... that is not the same as questions asking about the law or rights.  The law and rights are facts and not subject to opinion.  Advice is what you should do and that is opinion.  How can I do X is a process,  I have situation X i want result y in court is legal advice.  I have situation X I want result Y in my office is workplace advice, even if there are some legalities involved.

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings what about the first part, or splitting the close reasons?

Comment: You can only have 3 custom close reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I suggested [here](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4040/325), I propose:

> Questions about company-specific regulations, agreements, or policies should be directed to your manager, your HR department, or an attorney. Questions that address only a specific company or position are of limited use to future visitors. See [this post](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2695) for more information.

The linked meta post would, of course, be updated if we make this change.

I'm answering here too because we currently have two different questions about this same close reason and I think my suggestion addresses both of them.

With this wording I don't see the benefit of including the phrase "too narrow".

Comment: I'm not always too good with wording.  It comes and goes with me.

Answer (score 3):

### We need to keep a provision that prohibits questions seeking advice on company specific regulations.

These questions aren't usually applicable to others who might find the answers helpful, and often the topics that come up under these questions feel like troll-bait.

If the close reasons are adjusted, we should retain a provision against company-specific policies.

Comment: We could include it in the Description.  "To narrow:  questions such as company specific policies, and .... (fill in the rest)