# Can we revisit company specific close reason?

Tags: discussion

I asked this a few years ago....

[Question, should we eliminate or change the reason to close regarding company specific policies?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4039/question-should-we-eliminate-or-change-the-reason-to-close-regarding-company-sp)

I think it's time to revisit this, as this reason has become a bit of a hobgoblin to this site.

It appears to me that the mere mention of a specific company or policy inspires a mass rush to close a question even if it is answerable or if the question and answers could apply to other companies.

I believe we should drop this as a close reason. Of all close reasons, this one seems to be rarely used as intended, and most often reversed.

Comment: Do you feel this relates to the "happy trigger" people that I've seen some folks have complained recently that it has worsened a bit? Perhaps this increase in close and happy triggers is directly related to less tolerance on this aspect? Or is this a separate phenomena you've seen

Comment: @DarkCygnus This one has always seemed to be a particularly pernicious one.  The close as duplicate has calmed down a bit, partially because so many of us went nuts on that one, but this one persists, and it feeds the happy trigger way too much.  It seems to me that some people are looking for excuses instead of reasons

Comment: I thought the mere asking of any question inspires the mad rush to close it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know, I think we kind of need it because we do, from time to time, get questions were that is a valid close reason. I suppose if you were to remove the close reason, what would you replace it with?

**Question is too narrow** feels like a bad reason. Because a lot of questions and answered here are very very specific to particular problems, with no attempt to generalise either the question or answer. An example is the numerous questions that are asked about how long to wait before emailing HR. (Maybe this needs a dedicated close reason).

The solution, I feel, is education for those that are instinctively closing these questions.

I am able to see who has issued the close votes, but only after the question has been closed. So I can certainly comment on the question to challenge those people, but by then it's a bit late.