# Is this question asking for legal advice?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, close-reasons, legal-questions

I posted a question which was put on hold. Where exactly is [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/16812/7978) asking for legal advice ? I have read through [this entire thread](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1856/7978) and I don't see the question I ask fits even loosely as asking for legal advice, in the opinion of other members. I have clearly stated that all I want to do is be better prepared for such a situation in the future.

Comment: A down vote ? Care to explain down voter ?

Comment: bad questions get down votes.

Comment: @Chad. Although I would like to thank you for your insight, can you define bad questions? From my understanding of the tool tip on the down voting button, this particular question is clear, is useful and will help me become a better member.

Comment: I Disagree with you.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it's a legal question, but I'd close it as *unclear what you're asking*.

The problem isn't clear, nor is it clear what an appropriate answer would be.

As far as I can understand, the situation is as follows:

1. You do freelance work on a successful app
2. You list the freelance work on your resume
3. Company follows-up on your work history
4. App-company calls you up and makes a joke about royalties for using them as a reference

The real question seems to be, *"Why would they make that joke?"* which really, has nothing to do with contracts, and isn't something any of us can really know. I could speculate, but it would really be a shot in the dark.

Comment: Pretty close. The real question is, what can one do in order to be better prepared to handle such a situation in the future.

Comment: Also, would you think this is a peek on how casually members will vote to close a question without really understanding what the question is asking ?

Comment: The burden of making a question clear to the point where people can at least make a reasonable assumption of the problem is on the asker -- barring a minimal amount of clarity, there is no choice but to close the question since it can't be edited by any of us, and leaving it open won't make it any clearer. I also don't understand how you can better prepare yourself for friends making jokes? I think you are seeing a problem that nobody else is seeing, and unless you can have people understand your problem, nobody can help fix it.

Comment: @happybuddha: Also, you have to consider that if there's one Workplace.SE member who theoretically would be interested in rehabilitating a question back to a constructive form, it would be jmac. So if even he can't do this, then nobody can.

Comment: @jmac, I was talking about being better prepared for such situations in the future. The situation isn't friends making jokes, but previous employers talking about royalty checks in a humorous way. I can completely understand, if you don't understand the question at all.

Comment: @JimG. Going by your recent understanding of what asking legal advice is, I was beginning to think I was somehow, in a strange way, confusing you. But hey, thanks for the insight, jmac sure is an editing hero - no doubt about it.

Answer (score 1):

> I looked up the contract and there is no mention of such royalties.

Contracts are typically drawn up by a lawyer and enforced in a court of law.

Comment: So is *that* asking for legal advice ? I can *read* the contract. It is written in English. There is no mention of anything remotely related to royalties.

Comment: When you asked what you should do that was the legal advice question.