# (REOPENED) Reopen "Traveling time count as working"

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

The question **[Traveling time count as working](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/90266/traveling-time-count-as-working)** was closed for being a legal question. However, I believe this falls under the types of legal questions that most HR professionals should be able to answer. From [the Meta discussion](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1856/what-is-asking-for-legal-advice/1861#1861):

> Legal advice is asking a question that needs an answer by a lawyer,
>   not a HR manager or career guidance counselor.
>
> If the "legal" question is something that our site's target audience
>   should be expected to know the answer to, then the question is OK for
>   the site.
>
> For example, I would consider the following "legal" questions OK for
>   the site because they are things that HR managers should know the
>   answer to.
>
> - Is it legal to discriminate against smokers in one's company in    Canada or USA?
> - What is an equal opportunity employer?
> - What are the rules regarding electronic distribution of income data forms for tax reporting in the United States?

This question is about the interpretation of FLSA rules, which any HR professional should know. I believe that this question should be reopened.

Comment: I agree, I just edited it a bit too to make it a bit cleaner.

Comment: Whether you get paid for something as "travel time" or not is either (a) regulated by a union or federal entity (depends on country) or (b) covered under the contracted company policy. Both of which are mentioned in the closing votes.

Comment: Its a duplicate though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was improved and reopened.

Answer (score 0):

> This question is about the interpretation of FLSA rules.

No, it is not. Your question clearly states:"I did xyz, do I deserve payment for this?"

It is a specific legal question to an individual situation. The FLSA for example does not forbid to get paid for things that you don't have to get paid for. There might be a legal ground on which you could claim the right to get paid for, even if this right does not exist due to the FLSA. This would require a complete review of your legal situation.

Second, there might be even exemptions that are true for your individual situation that you don't even fall under FLSA rules. Again, this would require a complete review of your individual legal situation.

I cannot see that your question equals the same spirit of questions that you provided as on-topic example.