# Reopen "Employer doesn't want to pay me..." (REOPENED)

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request

The question **[Employer doesn't want to pay me because I took longer than estimated to finish the work](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/91400/employer-doesnt-want-to-pay-me-because-i-took-longer-than-estimated-to-finish-t)** was closed for being a legal question. However, I believe this falls under the types of legal questions that an HR professional should be able to answer. From [the Meta discussion](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1856/what-is-asking-for-legal-advice/1861#1861):

> Legal advice is asking a question that needs an answer by a lawyer,
>   not a HR manager or career guidance counselor.
>
> If the "legal" question is something that our site's target audience
>   should be expected to know the answer to, then the question is OK for
>   the site.
>
> For example, I would consider the following "legal" questions OK for
>   the site because they are things that HR managers should know the
>   answer to.
>
> - Is it legal to discriminate against smokers in one's company in    Canada or USA?
> - What is an equal opportunity employer?
> - What are the rules regarding electronic distribution of income data forms for tax reporting in the United States?

This question is about whether it is legal to not pay someone for work already completed. Any HR professional familiar with Slovakian or EU law should know the answer to this, and this one is clear enough that many non-HR professionals will know the answer. I believe that this question should be reopened.

Comment: Voted to reopen

Comment: I didn't see it as a legal question but one seeking an opinion on a company policy. That's why I voted to close it. At most it's "should I go see a lawyer?"

Comment: agreed, I VTRO as well