# Reopen request: Can my employer force me to open my office macbook? [done]

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

Can I ask for this question: [Can my employer force me to open my office macbook?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/103719/can-my-employer-force-me-to-open-my-office-macbook) to be re-opened? While it certainly has legal aspects I believe that  they are ones that a [competent HR manager should know](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1856/what-is-asking-for-legal-advice) and given we have the jurisdiction for the OP now it's answerable (and I've edited my answer that was posted pre-closure to include the appropriate info).

Comment: I think your answer already covers it, I doubt others may come that say something much different. But yes, this one is not asking for **legal advise** its just wondering if they can do that (not an advice on what legal actions to take). I think this is key to correctly VTC a "legal" question. Final vote to reopen.

Comment: I closed on the third vote because the location was missing. With that added this should be answerable in a general sense as your answer shows. I think your answer might actually belong more on a general "Can my employer..." question but there's a risk that that's too general to really answer properly.

Comment: @lilienthal yeah I left the other region info in my answer so as to make it potentially useful for future readers