# Codifying instructions for how to get a lawyer

Tags: discussion, legal-questions

In a recent [question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/112253/73255), one of the [answers](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/112257/73255) included the recommendation to essentially "get a lawyer". This spurred a discussion in the comments indicating that this advice is often included in Workplace answers and I don't disagree that it is a good idea. However, in the comments it is noted that "get a lawyer" is often "stand-alone" advice accompanied primarily by *reasons* that it should be done and *other things* that might be done as well, but no further details on how "get a lawyer" could be accomplished.

This seemed like something that warrants discussion and potentially action, but the comments section of an answer on a question about forging signatures doesn't seem like the optimal place for that discussion to occur so I wanted to make a less-prone-to-deletion place for further discussion.

There were a few main points brought up that need resolution:

1. Where should this information be located? Some options might be a Workplace Meta post, a normal Workplace.SE question, or maybe just a good external resource.
2. How should we address regional differences? It seems likely that not all regions have the same guidelines and even the basic "get a lawyer" advice might not be correct for the given situation in different areas. Options include having a "master post" that contains various details, or having separated posts by region so appropriate information can be provided.
3. Should this really be a separate post, or just additional information that "Get a lawyer" posts should include? There was some concern that a unified post would be too general to help in most specific situations, but there was also concern that including the details in the answer itself would be impractical.

Comment: So what do you want to discuss?

Comment: @DarkCygnus I've added a summary of the main discussion points that I'd like to see resolved.

Comment: Posted some thoughts, links and references on the matter

Answer (score 7):

> but no further details on how "get a lawyer" could be accomplished.

I think that no further details are given because no one can tell how *you* can get a lawyer.

It's not like we can share a link to a Lawer's Linkedin or webpage, as that may constitute a SPAM comment (as we would be promoting an individual for profit).

**The process of getting a lawyer should be completely up to the discretion of the OP**. It depends on what country you are, what budget you have, if you have already a preferred lawyer of trust, etc..

It reads *"get a laywer"*, but it actually means *"this is off topic, so instead of just voting to close I advise you to get professional legal help"*.

If you want, please read [What is asking for legal advice?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1856/73791) for more information on the matter.

We also have this from our [help center](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> What questions are off topic here?
>
> - Questions seeking company-specific advice on workplace regulations or policies, or **legal advice**

Furthermore, **even the guys at [Law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/) consider off-topic asking for legal advise:**

> Please don't ask questions seeking legal advice on a specific matter. These are **off-topic** for Law Stack Exchange. While users generally contribute answers in good faith, the answers are not legal advice, and contributors here are not your lawyer.

Comment: Besides the regional and personal preference variables, there's one of specialty. You don't go to the same doctor for as skin rash as for brain surgery, you probably also wouldn't go to the same lawyer for sexual discrimination as you would to help you buy a house.

Comment: Not to mention for a lot of people, the best "should you go to a lawyer?" question is answered by someone in their personal network in an informal conversation.

Comment: @ElysianFields true. now that you wrote it, the question *"should I go to a lawyer"* is also off-topic as it is asking for a specific choice

Comment: I think this answer is correct. How to obtain a lawyer is country-specific, sometimes even region specific. There's also the matter of finding one with the right specialization. All 'we' can say is 'you need to obtain legal advice from an expert'